# Build : Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)

Tags: android

Here is my existing **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fm.mess"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

.....
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/Androidplot-core-0.5.0-release.jar')
    compile files('libs/david-webb-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/lefu.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.4.3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
 }
```

**Note** : When, I build my app, I am not getting any errors.

But, Whenever I am adding dependency to support Firebase Messaging:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
```

**Getting :**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.jar

Comment: try adding compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0' to your build.gradle as well , since Firebase is asking for it as dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your local repository via the SDK Manager. It looks like `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'` depends on `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0`, which is not installed on your computer. This dependency is also not on Bintray, hence Gradle can't find it there - this is what the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

`support-v7` includes `android-support-v4` library. So the all method and class of `v4` are available inside the `v7`.

So if you add `v7` library then no need to add `v4` library.

```
com.android.support:support-v7:24.0.0
```